# Need help in using html 5 video tag with in php

Tags: php, css, html

Hello everyone I need help with this. I am using a small php script in which I have added HTML 5 video tag.

This part of the code is used to call the download function:

```
<?php print ("<a href='download.php?f=" .$f ."'><img src='" . img . "/" . $f . ".jpg' width= '440' height= '272'></a>"); ?>
<?php echo $string; ?>
<?php print("<a href='download.php?f=" .$f ."'>");  ?><img src= "http://example.com/images/button.jpg"> </a>
</ul>
<div class="black_right clearfix" style="">
<div class="text_91" style=""></div></div>
<h1><?php echo "$f" ?></h1>
```

Here is the video code:

```
<video width= "300" height= "250" controls>
    <source src= "http://www.example.com/photos/$f" type= "video/mp4">
</video>
```

What I am looking here is for a code that can call those video from a folder just like how the thumbnail is called with the $f from the folder "img".

Comment: i want to use something like this. <source src='" . video . "/" . $f . ".mp4' type= "video/mp4"> i tried this its not working.

Comment: no video with the supported format or MIME type found

Comment: Are you putting valid parameter in $f? And i see that your first image tag has ".img.". It's constant or variable without '$'?

Comment: img is a folder. i have written the code up here thats all i am using.

Comment: So if folder name 'img', why are you using it as PHP constant? "<img src='img/$f.jpg' width='440' height='272'>". In double quotes you can use php variable directly.

Comment: no that not giving me trouble i am having problem loading a video tag... please read my last comment on 1st answer

Comment: Print out everything and CTRl+U look what url to video is printed out. If you are printing wrong route to video via PHP, so you get error, that there is wrong video.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/home/user/videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Try to read the logs of your apache, maybe doesn't work because you are not using the variables in the correct way.

```
<?php print ("<a href='download.php?f=" .$f ."'><img src='" . $img . "/" . $f . ".jpg' width= '440' height= '272'></a>"); ?>
<?php echo $string; ?>
```

**Edit:**

```
<source src="example.com/videos/video.mp4"; type= "video/mp4">
```

If your folder videos is in your root directory use this, if not use something similar

```
<source src="/videos/video.mp4"; type= "video/mp4">
```

You can try this too:

```
<source src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/videos/video.mp4"; type= "video/mp4">
```

**And again... why the downvote, I was trying to help...**

Comment: I want to use some thing like this, but when i have enter this it says no video with supported format or Mime type found.<video width= "300" height= "250" controls>
<source src='" . video . "/" . $f . ".mp4' type= "video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: If VIDEO is a variable with the route to the folder with the videos put the $ simbol -> $video.

Comment: .... then put it inside the text string not like a php variable. 
<source src='video/". $f . ".mp4' type= "video/mp4">

Comment: No its still not running the video and giving the same not found error.

Comment: Check if the video exists in that route. Then check you are using the right route.

Comment: Yes the video exist and using the right route there is a folder in public_html and the file, that folder has videos in it.

Comment: The folder has the right permissions like 755 or the group is www-data or something like that.

Comment: Yes it has 755 set. no nothing like that. i am using a same function to call the thumbnail of the video but its not playing in video tag.

Comment: When i try to load the video from the straight path. <source src="http://www.example.com/videos/video.mp4" type= "video/mp4"> the video works. but when i try to load it the other way it does not

Comment: <video width= "300" height= "250" controls>
<source src='videos/". $f . ".mp4' type= "video/mp4">
</video>
Thats what m trying to do, what you are telling me is some thing else.

Comment: It's the same, the difference is the route you are using, you are not writing the valid one. Check the answer, maybe that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: No look that folder has a lot of videos in it and there is another folder which has all the thumbnails. there is one page at which the thumbnail is displayed plus with a video download button. now i am trying to add this video tag in that very page. what you are telling me is about a particular video.

Comment: It's an example just erase video.mp4 and put $f.'mp4'.